# Why is Doxygen reporting this method as an attribute?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a header file containing:

```
class ClassName {
...

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \fn boost::function<int(void *, char *)> ClassName::getFnPtr();
///
/// \brief ...
///
/// \author ...
/// \date ...
///
/// \return A boost function object ...
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

boost::function<int(void *, char *)> getFnPtr();

...
};
```

When running Doxygen, `getFnPtr()` is reported under "Public Attributes" instead of "Public Member Functions." Can anyone help me get Doxygen to put this in the right place?

I am new to Doxygen but familiar with Javadoc. I am using Doxygen GUI 1.8.1.

Edit: I think Doxygen is choking on the templated return type involving a boost function object. This post - [Doxygen fails to parse templated return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653356/doxygen-cannot-handle-return-value) - indicates that Doxygen doesn't handle the latest C++ changes. What version of C++ begins support for the boost function object return type? Can anyone point me to other examples of Doxygen being used for boost function object return type?

Comment: Probably because Doxygen does not have a C++ language precise parser (JavaDoc does).  That means Doxygen has to make mistakes in interpreting what a symbol means, and/or where it is defined, somewhere.   (Where it screws up depends on what part of C++ it doesn't implement).  It has always puzzled me that people use Doxygen in spite of this flaw.

Comment: @IraBaxter is there is something inherent in the code I posted that triggers a known bug in Doxygen? Or are you just saying "Doxygen has bugs so don't use it?" I have other very similar method declarations that work just fine. I must use Doxygen regardless, so can you identify the problem and help to solve it? BTW, you indicated that Javadoc has a C++ language precise parser. Do you mean Javadoc has a language precise _Java_ parser?

Comment: I meant that JavaDoc has (by analogy) a language-precise Java parser, correct.   No, I have no idea of the limitations of Doxygen's type resolver, except that real ones (we build one for a C++ front end) are enormous efforts and I have no reason to believe that effort has been made for Doxygen.   I'm saying, "Doxygen must have bugs" so I wonder why people use it.  One answer is they don't write complicated C++ programs and so what Doxygen does is "right enough".   If Doxygen fails on the complicated cases you have, it is failing precisely where it is needed the most.  Thus, my puzzlement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a typedef. Something along these lines:

```
typedef boost::function<int(void *, char *)> myfunc_t;
myfunc_t getFnPtr();
```

Comment: I will check if this works, but I do not want to alter code that would otherwise have been unchanged just to make Doxygen work.

Comment: Your typedef suggestion here does indeed result in the function being placed correctly. For now I'm holding out on a pure solution.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because I did apparently trigger a bug in Doxygen 1.8.1, and this workaround is the best solution I can find. Note the bug report mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that doxygen has some simple heuristics to distinguish between a function and a variable of type function pointer. The return type's template argument is what triggered the wrong decision in this case.

I'll correct this in the next release (>1.8.1), in the meantime you could use the workaround with the typedef as suggested by n.m. The related bug report is https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677315